# JSF Command Button to Open Message

Tags: java, jsf, button, message

I need to get a button in JSF to bring up a simple message box saying Hello World. How would i do this Simply?

Ive looked at many examples online but they all dont relate to what i want. They use JavaBean classes to store users values ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using primefaces, you should try this:

**XHTML:**

```
<p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />  

<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="HELLO" widgetVar="dlg1">  
    <h:outputText value="Hello world!" />  
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: The XHTML that im Using with my JSF are using h: rather than the P that you have.

Comment: The p means you are using primefaces components,

    <ui:composition 
    (..)
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">